# Browser Not setting the cookies for fetch api deployed on aws cloudfront

Tags: web, cookies, fetch, amazon-cloudfront

So I am making a request from `https://demos.thedomain.com` to `https://api.thedomain.com` with fetch options as:

```js
fetch('https://api.thedomain.com', {
  "body": {"username":"me@asdf.in","password":"qwerty"}",
  "credentials": "same-origin",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
})
```

and the response is:

[image]

And the browser doesn't set the cookies. Does anyone knows why this is happening ? The reason I put cloudfront's name in the question is because if I deploy the (exactly same)build to firebase and point route 53 to it, it works perfectly but when I deploy it to S3 for cloudfront and repoint using cloudfront CNAME it fails to set the cookies. I have tried setting secure: true,false both. If any more details is required, just ask.

Comment: can you try domain=.thedomain.com in the set-cookie and try ? Seems like you're accessing a subdomain.

Comment: @james that's been depreciated for all browser versions that came after 2012 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265 ) domain.com sets cookies for all subdomains. Even if you send .domain , browsers ignore leading dot. But just to be safe, I already tried that .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending the request to a remote server at subdomain https://api.thedomain.com. This means your request is being made cross-site and the Access-Control headers on the response should be defined and `withCredentials` set to `true`.

I see that you have already set the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header to be `true` and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to specifically denote your client subdomain at https://demos.thedomain.com in the response headers.

Change the

```
"credentials": "same-origin"
```

attribute in your fetch request to

```
"credentials": "include"
```

and you should now see the cookies being set on your browser.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch